# What tool adds unlimited clipboard and searchable retrieval?

Tags: clipboard, clipboard-manager

In OS X, the Alfred Powerpack lets users search and retrieve from their clipboard history for a while. [Albert](https://github.com/ManuelSchneid3r/albert), the Alfred lookalike for Linux, doesn't appear to have that feature.

What tools will let me search and access old entries from my clipboard history? Is there a search option in GPaste?

Answer (score 1):

Diodon (a clipboard manager) [has a search feature](https://answers.launchpad.net/diodon/+question/267872).

Give it a try ;)